# Bugs on windrose in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am using following code to generate windrose in highcharts:

```
$(function () {

    // Parse the data from an inline table using the Highcharts Data plugin
    $('#container_rose').highcharts({
     data: {
      table: 'freqency',
      startRow: 1,
      endRow: 17,
      endColumn: 7
     },

     chart: {
         polar: true,
         type: 'column'
     },

     credits: {
           enabled: false
         },

     title: {
         text: 'Wind Rose(Last 30-days)'
     },

     pane: {
      size: '90%'
     },

     legend: {
      reversed: true,
      align: 'right',
      verticalAlign: 'top',
      y: 100,
      layout: 'vertical'
     },

     xAxis: {
      tickmarkPlacement: 'on'
     },

     yAxis: {
         min: 0,
         endOnTick: false,
         showLastLabel: true,
         title: {
          text: 'Frequency (%)'
         },
         labels: {
          formatter: function () {
           return this.value + '%';
          }
         }
     },

     tooltip: {
      valueSuffix: '%',
      followPointer: true,
      valueDecimals: 2
      },

     plotOptions: {
         series: {
          stacking: 'normal',
          shadow: false,
          groupPadding: 0,
          pointPlacement: 'on'
         }
     }
 });
});
```

It is showing the chart as following when I am clicking on a button from front-end.
[image]

But the problem is when I am clicking on the button second time it is showing the chart as following (but it should display the chart as the first chart):
[image]

Why it is showing wrong chart after multiple click on the button. How can I fix the bug.

Comment: So it looks like your data has changed. Just check what kind of data is passed to the chart and paste here as an update of question.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since you don't show what this button does I can only guess that it is re-adding the data again to your chart. If you do not want this to happen you need to capture the 2nd button click event somehow. Without seeing the code used I cannot begin to guess on which method would be appropriate.

Comment: Actually I am using a button in jsf. Clicking on button calling a method and get the data list. Then I just pass the datalist to the highcharts as following:
http://jsfiddle.net/gnTLA/

Comment: What is the method? That jsFiddle link is all kinds of broken. For example: `Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #container3_#{status0.index}`